# checkboxes list status with linq

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

Consider this scenario where you want to retrieve a List or IEnumerable of the values of all the unchecked checkboxes in checkboxlist. this code gives me the value of all checked (now) or (previously). how can I get the values of unchecked (now) and (previously) with linq. thank you

```
private IEnumerable <string > selectedValues
    {
        get
        {
    if (ViewState ["selectedValues"] == null  && chapp . SelectedIndex  >=-1 )
    {
        ViewState ["selectedValues"]= chapp .Items.Cast <ListItem >()
            .Where (li=>li.Selected )
            .Select (li=>li.Value )
            .ToList ();
    }else 
        ViewState ["selectedValues"]= Enumerable .Empty <string >();
            return (IEnumerable <string >)ViewState ["selectedValues"];
        }
        set {ViewState ["selectedValues"] = value ;}
        }
protected void chapp_SelectedIndexChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     CheckBoxList c = (CheckBoxList)sender;

   var oldselection = this.selectedValues;
     var newSelection = c.Items.Cast<ListItem>()
                 .Where(li => li.Selected  )
                 .Select(li => li.Value);
     var unchangedItems = newSelection.Except(oldselection );

 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on you comment:
Let's say that you have aspx page which load all the applications you have (from active directory, DB or whatever), after that assigning all the applications which the current user have (also getting those applications from what ever) ... so in your Page_Load you will have something like below:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        //Load all applications
        var apps = loadAllApplications();
        //Load user applications
        var myApps = loadUserApplications();

        //Bind to checkboxlist, assuming my checkboxlist ID "chksApps"
        chksApps.DataSource = apps.Select(x => new ListItem
        {
            Value = x.Id.ToString(),
            Text = x.Name,
            Selected = myApps.Any(a => x.Id == a)
        });
        chksApps.DataBind();
    }
}

//lets say I have a Application class like that
public class Application
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

private List<int> loadUserApplications()
{
    // if user already have "Paint", "Chrome" assigned
    var myApps = new List<int>() { 2, 4 };
    return myApps;
}

private List<Application> loadAllApplications()
{
    //for testing I will create a dummy list of applications
    var applications = new List<Application>() { 
        new Application { Id = 1, Name = "Visual Studio" },
        new Application { Id = 2, Name = "Paint" },
        new Application { Id = 3, Name = "Notepad" },
        new Application { Id = 4, Name = "Chrome" }
    };
    return applications;
}
```

so till now the user will be able to check, uncheck what ever he want. so your checkboxlist `AutoPostBack = False`

so when he finish editing, assuming he will submit that to the server so he will have a submit button (lets say it's ID is "btnSave"

```
 protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     //Load user applications
     var myApps = loadUserApplications();

     //get selected Application
     var selectedApps = chksApps.Items.Cast<ListItem>()
                            .Where(x => x.Selected)
                            .Select(x => int.Parse(x.Value)).ToList();

     // send request to owner to add those below apps for user "newSelectedApps"
     var newSelectedApps = selectedApps.Except(myApps).ToList();

     // send request to owner to remove those below apps "newUnSelectedApps"
     var newUnSelectedApps = myApps.Except(selectedApps).ToList();

     // those below are the unchanged apps "unChangedApps"
     var unChangedApps = myApps.Intersect(selectedApps).ToList();
 }
```

this is better than using `ViewState` for performance

Comment: Hi Sherif Ahmed, I'm getting the erro below: System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: Le type 'System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2[[System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a],[System.String, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]' dans l'assembly 'System.Core, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'

Comment: this error is appearing under var unSelectedChanged = oldUnSelected.Except(newUnSelected); second

Comment: Hi Ahmed, thanks for this,  but the newUnselected and oldUnselected has the same values. let say in my list I have the following list: apple checked, orange checked, pear unchecked and banana unchecked. if unchecked apple and checked banana, I want to see under the newUnselected : apple and oldUnseleceted : pear . and under newSelected : banana and oldSelected : orange.

Comment: Hi Codes, can you explain me what do you really want to achieve from that? may be i have another way or another solution for you problem

Comment: Hi Ahmed, what I'm trying to do is provide a user a list of application to select from and based on the selection a request is submitted to the application owner to grant access. in order for me to do that I need to know what application the user selected, unselected and what hasn't changed. I got a tabcontainer with mutiple tabpanels filed with the list of application from active directory. thanks a lot